Stripe Connect Test onboarding AccountLink with Standard accounts and direct charges
I have understood how to pre-fill dummy data when testing onboarding, like DOB 1901-01-01 etc... as described here: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/testing
Now i need to test the onboarding flow by connecting an existing Stripe Standard account.
The first thing is to enter the email, then verify a security code (e.g. via phone) and finally access my email to click on a verification link.
And here's my hard time to figure out, what email to use, since skipping the email is only possible in Express onboarding.
On the other side, i have setup different test accounts (connected to my primary account and same email) but that makes no sense, since i am connecting to my platform account itself.
As the documentation states:

Warning Don’t connect the platform account to itself—that fails to
reflect the real world use of Connect, and makes debugging difficult.

Do i need to setup an additional account (with different email) with Stripe?
What if i want to test two or more dummy accounts?

I think by "Don't connect the platform account to itself" the documentation means "Don't get your platform account (acct_x) to be a connected account of said platform (acct_x)".
I feel like this documentation may be outdated, since I don't know how you would do this, but anyway, connecting Standard accounts that are set with the same email is fine, for testing purposes. In production, it would probably raise 'money-laundering' red flags.
About test Standard accounts, there is no way to bypass some of the onboarding, like you can with Express accounts. This is due to the inherent independence that Standard accounts have - they are all real accounts, with no notion of 'test' to them aside from being connected to your platform's test environment.
It's worth mentioning that with Platform controls - the ability for the platform to control the Standard account's payout schedule and payment methods - and the new oAuth behavior - that of only allowing one Platform per Standard account - Standard accounts are in many ways closer to Express accounts now, so you could still leverage them for part of your testing.

Yes Lucky, i agree with that but then, the whole documentation about testing the implementation is worthless without being able to test the flow. Except setting up some connected accounts manually (trough the dashboard) and test the paymentIntent etc only. Which i did and it works fine. But if you need to test the flow (as user experience) the whole thing is worth nothing. Another case to consider is, how to test onboarding NEW accounts, interruption, resuming of the flow etc etc. Using accounts with (same) shared email has some serious downsides.

Like what Lucky mentioned, you shouldn't connect your platform account to itself. Yes, you can and should setup a new Standard account. You can always append the plus + sign after your email address (see here for more details) for a different email address.

I understand your concerns, but if you're using Standard onboarding, new accounts, interruptions, resuming the flow would all be out of your control, since the onboarding is entirely managed by Stripe anyway. If your user has any issue with their onboarding it would be an issue between them and Stripe, as outlined here https://docs.stripe.com/connect/accounts#choosing-approach

The main concern is not really (only) the email, but there are a lot of reasons in the background why someone would need to save the status of the connected account into a SaaS database. One of them is, for example, to enable card payments for that account only if status is OK etc. There are hundreds of factors which influence how you build your app to reflect real world behavior of onboarding users which use your SaaS business

You can use a new email address to sign up a new Stripe account. If you are using Gmail, you can put a + and alphanumeric characters after your username (for example `test+new@gmail.com) and use this new address to sign up for an account.

and how do you catch the verification link sent to your inbox? That means, you sign up for a brand new Stripe account?

You will still receive the verification link in your original inbox (i.e., test@gmail.com)
